# Is there a way to add data into a specific row c#

Tags: c#, csv

I have a csv file that has data like

1, FirstName, LastName, DOB

2, FirstName, LastName, DOB

3, FirstName, LastName, DOB

4, FirstName, LastName, DOB

I was wondering if I was able to replace say the 3rd row with 3, John, Smith, 01/12/1999. I already have this saved in a string I just need to be able to overwrite a specific row, in this case row 3. Thanks

Comment: It would be really appreciated to include the code snippet about what you've done and what you've tried.

Comment: It's out of context, I am currently trying to edit data in a csv file in the format above. So far what i have done is edit a particular row and save that as a string now I am just trying to add it back into the csv file. However if I use File.WriteAll text or something like that the data will be put at the end of the csv file, whereas I want the data to go in a specific row (editing 3rd row I want to overwrite the 3rd row of data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you want has (almost) nothing to do with `csv`, but it can be done with some string manipulation.

```cs
private string yourFilePath;

private void EditRow(int rowNum, string edit)
{
    string[] rowsArray = IO.File.ReadAllLines(yourFilePath);
    rowsArray[rowNum] = edit;
    IO.File.WriteAllLines(yourFilePath, rowsArray);
}
```

As I know, there is no way to edit specific row of the file without opening it. So the code above just opens it all, edit the specific row, and overwrites entire file.

See also: [System.IO.File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to read a whole file and overwrite the whole file in one go unless the file is small. It's also a good idea to only save to a temporary file and then delete and rename to ensure you were able to succeed in writing the update before deleting the old file.